# How do I open the html page content with ms word

Tags: javascript, ms-word

How do I open the html page content with ms word
[javascript code]

Comment: What is it you need to be exported? You wan't to create a MS Word document from Javascript?

Comment: You mean that you want script you can put on an HTML page to create a word document? Or do you mean you want to copy HTML text into a word document including JavaScript that will run within Word? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Just have your server send the HTML document with MIME type of application/msword